# Why does my A record get ignored and how to set up own DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-hosting

I am trying to set up my own dns server on Ubuntu 18.04 using bind9. I installed the needed packages and have following files under /etc/bind

named.conf

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

named.conf.options

```
acl "trusted" {
    127.0.0.1;
    192.168.1.0/24;
};
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;
    auth-nxdomain no;
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    //custom additions
    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { trusted; };
    listen-on { trusted; };
    allow-query { trusted; };
    allow-transfer { none; };
    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };
};
```

named.conf.default-zones

```
...
zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};
...
```

db.local

```
$TTL 604800
@ IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
    3; Serial
    604800; Refresh
    86400; Retry
    2419200; Expire
    604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@ IN NS localhost.
@ IN A 127.0.0.1
@ IN AAAA ::1
; custom additions
router IN A 192.168.1.1
```

now in my setup I have a router which gives ips in the range `192.168.1.10-200`. I have pc D which I'm trying to set up bind with the ip `192.168.1.8`, to be able to later point my router dns entry to it, instead of the router itself which it is configured right now. Now on pc D I set my ip, netmask, gateway manually to `192.168.1.8, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.1.1` and the dns I set manually to `127.0.0.1`. I can confirm that `127.0.0.1` is being used by the pc by running `systemd-resolve --status` which gives me `DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1 and DNS Domain: ~.`

Now to my questions: Am I right that `@` in db.local refers to `localhost.` and gets appended to each resource record which does not end with a dot? So `router IN A 192.168.1.1` becomes `router.localhost. IN A 192.168.1.1` and is thus a FQDN?
I then restarted bind with `sudo service bind9 restart` and checked that it is running with `sudo service bind9 status` which shows me `Active: active (running)`
Now here I probably don't understand something, but I would have now expected `ping router.localhost` to try to ping `192.168.1.1` but instead I get the weird response:

```
PING router.localhost(ip6-localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_sq=1 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_sq=2 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_sq=3 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
```

Why is this happening? And how can I achieve my goal of being able to add A records in db.local and then be able to ping for example printer.localhost and it pings another ip in my network e.g. `192.168.1.5`?

EDIT:
Running `dig router.localhost` returns:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION
router.localhost. 0 IN A 127.0.0.1
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
```

which is strange and I already noticed that `systemd-resolve --status` and the file /etc/resolve.conf don't agree, that file has:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

I'm not sure where that 53 ip is coming from.

Comment: you server is enabled for both ip v4 and and ipv6. Do you need ipv6 for you network?

Comment: not really, but I would like to be able to do both. I tried to set `listen-on-v6 { none; };` but with the same strange ping message as a result

Comment: What does `/etc/hosts` look like, is that where the other address comes from? (And listening on v4/v6 does not affect what records are returned, only over which protocols you can receive queries)

Comment: I didn't change /etc/hosts it is standard. I did add once a line, this worked great. But then I removed it again

Comment: Or, in other words, start with testing by querying the nameserver specifically (using eg `dig`), before you test the whole resolver config for client applications with something like `ping`

Comment: Thank you @HåkanLindqvist your comment put me on the right path.

Comment: as a side note , don't forget to add ipv6 address to your acl "trusted".  Remember ipv6 is 'another new network', so anything you do for v4 you need to replicate to v6!!!!

Comment: You see `ip6-localhost` because Ubuntu inherited this bizarre behavior from Debian. It is an address listed for `::1` in the `/etc/hosts` file. Nobody uses it, it's not standard, and it really should not be there.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, I was hitting: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10298

I fixed it by a symlink: `sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`